# How to do computational operations in Stream Java8?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

**What I have:**

```java
List<String> allGroupsPoint = Arrays.asList(
                "1.0 1.0 1.0 4.0 5.0 4.0 5.0 1.0",
                "1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0",
                "1.0 1.0 1.0 4.0 5.0 4.0 5.0 1.0");
```

**STEP 1:** need convert all Strings from `List<String> allGroupsPoint` to `List<Point[]> arrayPoints` through my method `double[] dataParser.parse(String s)`.
**STEP 2:**  I get for each line arrays `double[]`:

```
double[] digits = dataParser.parse(String s)
```

The size of each array will be 8 (since there are only 8 digits from one String)

**STEP 3:** Need this arrays `double` convert to Object `Point[]` to get `4` objects (2 numbers per 1 object). Like this:

```java
Point p1 = new Point(digits[0], digits[1]);
Point p2 = new Point(digits[2], digits[3]);
Point p3 = new Point(digits[4], digits[5]);
Point p4 = new Point(digits[6], digits[7]);
```

**STEP 4:** to wrap up `p1`, `p2`, `p3`, `p4` to `List<Point[] x>`.

I tried this, but isn't work:

```java
List<Point[]> test = allGroupsPoint.stream()
                .map(s -> dataParser.parseString(s))
                .map(Point[]::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I don't know how in Stream do **STEP 3**.

Comment: What is the result of `dataParser.parseString(s)` ?

Comment: Write a convert function for `double[]` to `Point[]` and map like `.map(e -> convert(e))` instead `.map(Point[]::new)`

Comment: @YCF_L method `dataParser.parseString(s)` splits the string into an array double []

Comment: @Rono, write you message how answer, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
List<String> allGroupsPoint = Arrays.asList(
    "1.0 1.0 1.0 4.0 5.0 4.0 5.0 1.0",
    "1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 7.0 8.0",
    "1.0 1.0 1.0 4.0 5.0 4.0 5.0 1.0");

List<Point[]> arrayPoints = allGroupsPoint.stream()
    .map(line -> dataParser.parse(line)) // or .map(line -> dataParser.parseString(line))
    .map(array -> IntStream.range(0, array.length / 2)
        .mapToObj(i -> new Point(array[i * 2], array[i * 2 + 1]))
        .toArray(Point[]::new))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

for (Point[] x : arrayPoints)
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(x));
```

output:

```
[Point(1.0, 1.0), Point(1.0, 4.0), Point(5.0, 4.0), Point(5.0, 1.0)]
[Point(1.0, 2.0), Point(3.0, 4.0), Point(5.0, 6.0), Point(7.0, 8.0)]
[Point(1.0, 1.0), Point(1.0, 4.0), Point(5.0, 4.0), Point(5.0, 1.0)]
```

Comment: How from `Stream<List<Point>>`  get all objects `Point` (always size is 4 elements of `Point`)  and pass to constructor class, example, `Quadrangle(Point p1, Point p2, Point p3, Point p4)`?

Comment: `stream.map(x -> new Quadrangle(x.get(0), x.get(1), x.get(2), x.get(3)))`